# SpamAssassin: Can't locate Mail/SpamAssassin/Bayes.pm

Tags: permissions, spamassassin

Running `spamassassin --lint` results in error message:

```
Can't locate Mail/SpamAssassin/Bayes.pm:   Keine Berechtigung at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin.pm line 1770, <DATA> line 717.
(Keine Berechtigung -> Access denied)
```

Running the same command as root succeeds. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down the problem to line

```
require Mail::SpamAssassin::Bayes;
```

in `/usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin.pm`. The module cannot be loaded here.

However, when copying the same line to the top of the file (where others `require`s are), everything works fine. The same line I copied to the top of files: `/usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin/BayesStore.pm` and `/usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/Bayes.pm`

Similarly, I added `require Mail::SpamAssassin::BayesStore::DBM;` to top of `/usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/Bayes.pm`.

This fixed the problem for me.